# Does custom header show up in Networks tab of browser after being set using Browsermob-Proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, header

I've set custom request headers via REST API based on Browsermob-Proxy: 
POST /proxy/[port]/headers - Set and override HTTP Request headers. For example setting a custom User-Agent. However, the header doesn't show up in my Network tab of my browser.

Can I expect to see the custom request header show up in the Network tab of my browser who is configured to the corresponding proxy? If not, how can I make it show up in the Networks tab using python?

Comment: "Can I expect to see the custom request header show up in the Network tab of my browser who is configured to the corresponding proxy?" - Have you not tried doing this before posting. It should be shown in the Network tab.

Comment: I have. What I meant was I don't know if my request worked properly and if I should expect it to show up in the Networks tab.

Comment: Yes it should show up in the Network tab.

Comment: If you want to see it using Python, you can debug the request object being sent.

Comment: In that case, is my REST API call correct?

curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/proxy/8081/headers -d '{"Nancy-header": "True"}'

When I look in the browser after entering this command in the terminal, Nancy-header does not show up in the Networks tab. How would I go about debugging the request object? Thanks for your help so far by the way! P.S. my localhost:8080 proxy port is on 8081.